# Nested accordion menu in Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I have a problem and can't find a solution.
I am making an accordion menu in jquery and want the second level of the menu to open one at a time.

and would like to use this on a website any help in how to get this to stay open when the page reloads.

my first time asking so sorry if it is not readable.

hope anybody can help.

I am a noob in this kind of stuff.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  menuHead = $('.slide-list li a').click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).next().toggle("slow");
  });    
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;   
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
}

a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;
}

a:visitied {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;  
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #CCC;
}


#menu-wrapper {

}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li {
  list-style-type: none;    
}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li a.selected {
  color: #F00;  
}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li ul {
  display: none;    
}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li ul li ul {
  display: none;    
}
```

```html
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="slide-list">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void()">menu item 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item 1 level 2</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item level 3</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item 2 level 2</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item level 3</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void()">menu item 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item 1 level 2</a>
              </li>
          </ul>     
      </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void()">menu item 3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look http://jsbin.com/ecupit/edit#javascript,html,live How you mean one at a time?

Comment: Indeed. If you're saying that you want each 'list-item' to display 'one list-item at a time', then you would need to use a $.each function, injunction with setTimeout (or delay()) and use multiples of the index as the delay. such as `$.each($(this).next(), function(index,value){setTimeout(function(){ $(value).toggle; }, index*1000);});`

Comment: I think the key question here is having the menu to stay open when the page reloads

Comment: When the page reloads, do you want the previous opened menu to stay open or a certain(constant) menu item to stay open?

Comment: Yes i want that a certain link is clicked that the page loads and the menu stated is on that page. So you know where you are on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
if(window.location.hash.length > 0){
  var $licurrent = $($('.slide-list li').get(window.location.hash.replace('#','')));
  $licurrent.parents("ul").show();
  $licurrent.find("ul:first").show();
  $licurrent.find("a:first").addClass("selected");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slide-list li a').click(function(e) {                     
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      var $licurrent = $(this).parent();
      window.location.hash = $('.slide-list li').index($licurrent);

      $licurrent.parent().find("li").not($licurrent).find("ul").hide("slow");
      $(this).next("ul").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;    
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;    
}

a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;
}

a:visitied {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000;    
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #CCC;
}


#menu-wrapper {

}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li {
  list-style-type: none;  
}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li a.selected {
  color: #F00;    
}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li ul {
  display: none;  
}

#menu-wrapper ul.slide-list li ul li ul {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="slide-list">
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:void()">menu item 1</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item 1 level 2</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item level 3</a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item level 4</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item 2 level 2</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item level 3</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:void()">menu item 2</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="javascript:void()">submenu item 1 level 2</a>
              </li>
          </ul>     
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:void()">menu item 3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code will add the hash in URL and when you refresh the page you could find that menu selected.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to make the menu stay open when the page reloads, not sure if it is the previously opened menu or a certain menu

Comment: Yes its what you say Huangism i want the menu to be left as it is when you click on a link and change from page. So you don't need to open the hole menu again and again. Thanks you all for your suggestions. I am sorry i did not answer any of you i was busy with school. This weekend as of tomorrow i will check all your comments and tell you if it is what i wanted. I will also try to make a illustration of how i would like it to be so everybody knows what i mean.

Comment: Its exactly what i ment can you tell me how it works so i know whats happening so i learn from it. O and those this stay open with a link in a href like try.com/contact.html.

Comment: @user1466939 This just a pure html nothing else, i am just adding the current index of active li element in the URL through hash. basically the "#" are used to navigate to a position on a page.

Comment: O oke i see. does this also work with the menu that has links in them. i want to implement this in a website where the menu will be the main menu. with links to the other pages where the same menu is used. Can i do this with that or is this a other way.

Comment: @user1466939 the links are already in the <li> element so definitely it will work for them as well.

Comment: I am building a site with this menu as the main menu to go to other pages so from try.com/index.html to try/contact.html thats when i want the menu to tell you are on the contact page so the menu will open and be selected. please help or direct me to a tutorial so i can learn maybe a book or something just want to finish this and want to learn how of course. thank you.

Comment: @user1466939 are you using any server side scripting or using only the html?

Comment: @user1466939 if you are using only html than your each page must have the same menu and if so than just add the some class i.e. "current" to your related menu and put the jquery code to open it in document.ready() function. Mark me as an answer if its fulfill your requirement.

Comment: it worked thank you very much. Would you like to explain what you did or what the code does so i can inderstand and learn. Like this $(li)<--this selects all li in the dom. Thank you again